# R Markdown to PDF, how to add whitespace (tab, space) between Static and dynamic content

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, knitr

I woudl like to generate letters which will be signed by 2 people. One of them (CEO) is always the same,  the second is dynamic. Both have titles. How can I add whitespace in the lines between the static and dynamic contents? for example

```
StaticPerson1                      DynamicPerson
CEO                                DynamicTitleofDynamicPerson
```

note the the elements of both columns should be properly aligned.

my code is

```
NameofCEO                     `r db$name`
CEO                           `r db$position`
```

however when I knit the document to PDF it becomes garbled up like

NameofCEO                     Name
CEO                           Position

Comment: could you please write this as an answer?

Comment: how can I use use space characters as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\hspace`

**For example:**

````
```{r}
my_words <- c("mia", "Maria")
```

Mamma\hspace{75mm}`r my_words[1]`
\newline
Santa\hspace{75mm} `r my_words[2]`
````

[image]

Comment: you mean hspace right?

Comment: @ECII Yes, certainly :) You can accept my answer ;)